# What is the significance of the asteroid belt?

Tags: asteroids, asteroid-belt

This may seem like a trivia question or a question for skeptics, but I really would like to know, *what is the significance of the asteroid belt?* The only reason I've seen from my research is "because it's there", but I'd like to know a more scientific reason. Evolutionists state the reason is "because the Belt will give us more clues to the formation of the Solar System"; but I don't buy into that theory. Some dreamers say that asteroids may one day be mined for precious minerals; but this is only a far-off dream.

Theses three reasons given are all unsatisfactory; could a professional or knowledgeable amateur astronomer help me out here?

Comment: I'm an astronomer, and to me "because it's there" is sufficient.

Comment: Evolutionists??

Comment: Studying the asteroid belt does give us important knowledge on how the Solar System was formed.  There are bodies in it that are practically untouched since the formation of our solar system, and we can learn a lot about the conditions which formed them.

Comment: @DavidHammen Perhaps it is a synonym for scientist.

Comment: @RobJeffries Some scientists-- even some astronomers-- are Christians, in case you didn't know.

Comment: @GuessWho How is that relevant to your use of the term "evolutionist"? It sounds like you are trying to claim that there is some sort of alternative *scientific* viewpoint. Which there isn't.

Comment: I have voted to close as Unclear what you are asking. The asteroid belt doesn't need a reason to exist. It just is there because of physics. Evolutionists **don't** argue it is there to teach us anything. Scientists are happy to use its existence to provide partial explanations or theories.

Comment: I voted to re-open because this question can be read in two ways.  "Because it's there" is nice but it lacks detail.   The asteroid belt is very specific.  There's not enough mass for it to form in a planet.  Also, Jupiter's gravitational effect helps keep it apart.   It might have formed into a planet or possibly part of Mars if not for Jupiter's migration early in the formation of the solar system.  There are answers to this question beyond "because it's there".

Comment: What's the significance of the asteroid belt? Other planets? Planets' moons? Other galaxies? Extrasolar planets? Why do these things need to have a significance? Not everything (by which I mean nothing) in the Universe was put here for the enjoyment or benefit of humans.

Answer (score 5):

> The only reason I've seen from my research is "because it's there", but I'd like to know a more scientific reason.

"Because it's there" **is** a scientific reason. Couple that with the fact that we know there's a whole lot of stuff we don't know about the asteroids makes studying the asteroids interesting from a pure scientific perspective.

That studying asteroids yields insights into the formation of the solar system makes such studies relevant. That asteroids have caused significant damage to the Earth (e.g., the Chicxulub impact event) and can do so again makes such studies even more relevant. That asteroids might well be a trove of wealth makes such studies more relevant still.